# Change my apps bundle identifier

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

in Xcode 4.4.1 how do I change my apps bundle identifier.

I started on top of an example project and want to clean up the mess.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Project navigator select you project. In the resulting editor view, select your target from the list on the left side. The first field in the Summary tab is the Bundle Identifier. You can also update this value by going to the Info tab on the same view and editing the Bundle identifier property in the Custom iOS Target Properties section.